# Acer Aspire and Radeon Graphic Card

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, amd-graphics, acer

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and checked the need for additional drivers via HW Probe. [Here](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=32c519104f) the results, and as you can see the driver for the graphic card doesn't properly work. I should change the *parameters of the kernel*. Can you suggest me how to do it without screwing it?

Comment: Are you really suffering from graphic card problems? Or do you believe you might potentially have problems because the website said so?

Comment: Not sure about it. I tried a couple of apps that exist both for linux and windows, and they looked clunkier. It might be that the linux versions are just poorly written

Answer (score 0):

You are using `fbdev` driver currently. Try to remove `nomodeset` from your kernel boot options [1] and upgrade kernel to a latest one [2] to use `amdgpu` or `radeon` drivers.

[1] [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

[2] https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds